# Every selectedTest exists in the data-Test array and get results

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

HTML

```
<div class="col-test" data-test="Swimming pools|Fitness center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet trash|Washer">
```

User selected multiple option from dropdown and get values

```
var test = $('#options').val();
console.log(test); // Array [ "Swimming pools", "Fitness center" ]
```

Here's the psudo code

```
for each selectedTest data (from multiselect input)
  check if it exists in the data-test array
    if it does not exists:
              then show = false
    otherwise:
              do nothing and continue to check the next selectedTest (no code is needed here)
```

There's issue with below code. I need to make sure that every selectedTest exists in the data-Test array. It doesn't return resulted as expected. There's something issue with code.

```
data-test="Swimming pools|Fitness center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet trash|Washer"

var $variable = $('.col-test');
   if(test && test != null && test.length > 0) {
                console.log($varible.data('test'));
                var arryTest = $varible.data('test').split("|");
                arryTest.forEach((singleTest) => { 
                  if(!test.includes(singleTest)){
                    show = false;
                  }else{
                     //do nothing and continue to check the next selected Amenity
                  }
                });
              }
```

I can see in console is printing data-test results over and over again. I think Loop is not working.

Results

> Swimming pools|Fitness
> center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet trash|Washer
>
> Swimming pools|Fitness
> center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet
> trash|Washer|Swimming pools|Fitness
> center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet trash|Washer
>
> Swimming pools|Fitness
> center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet
> trash|Washer|Swimming pools|Fitness
> center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet
> trash|Washer|Swimming pools|Fitness
> center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet trash|Washer

Comment: Please provide an example of the test data. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty I have edited question and added example of the test data.

Comment: I see the update yet it is still not reproducible. Where is `$varible` defined? Where is the HTML? What errors do you see in Console if any?

Comment: @Twisty I have updated again.

Comment: Thank you for the update. You state, "*User selected multiple option from dropdown...*" yet I do not see this in the HTML, I do not see a form or a Select element of any type. There is no way to replicate the issue in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var dataTest = $("#col-test").val().split("|");
  console.log(dataTest);
  $("#user-options").append("<option>Item 1</option>");
  $.each(dataTest, function() {
    $("#user-options").append("<option>" + this + "</option>");
  });
  $("#user-options").append("<option>Last Item</option>");
  $("#user-options").change(function() {
    var show = true;
    var options = $(this).val();
    console.log("Selected Options", options);
    $.each(options, function(i, o) {
      if (dataTest.indexOf(o) == -1) {
        show = show && false;
      }
    });
    console.log(show);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="col-test" value="Swimming pools|Fitness center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet trash|Washer" />
<select id="user-options" multiple>
</select>
```

When the User makes a selection, a `change` event is triggered. When there is a `change` the User's selection will be compared to the List of options. If the Option has a index of `-1`, it does not exist in the list and `show` will be set to false.

I did not have a complete set of options, so I had to build a list based on the only data that I have, which means all options selected will be in the list and you get `true`. So I added "Item 1" and "Last Item". If either are selected, you get `false`.

Comment: Just saw this. Let me replicate this on my end. I'll let you know.

Comment: what if I would like to display results in form of `<div class="col-test" data-test="Swimming pools|Fitness center|Parking|Washer|Spa|Parking|Clubhouse|Valet trash|Washer">..... </div>` rather than `console.log(show);` ?

Comment: @Nisarg you can do that if you want.

Comment: can you please edit in your answer? Thanks

Comment: @Nisarg I not going to. I would advise you to try it on your own, see if someone has already posted about it, or do further research. If you still are unable to work it out, at that time, pose a new question to SO. You should be able to add the new elements with the `options` array joined by "|" with relative ease. It's not clear to me where you want that to be added.